# Unable to get URL in mozilla in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Mozilla 51.0.1 and Eclipse Lunar 3.0.1. When I am trying to run my code I am not able to get URL in the browser, it just opens.

```
package SessionPack;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SessionCalss {

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        System.out.println("String"); 

        WebDriver driver;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\New folder\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 

         driver.get("www.gooogle.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: what's in console?

Comment: What is the Selenium and Gecko version that you are using? And what's the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Your request is wrong in two places:

1. You write extra character "o" - `gooogle`
2. You have to added `https://` before URL-adress - `https://www.google.com`

After fix this code will be work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `http://` or `https://` specifically; you have to change your URL string from:

```
 www.gooogle.com to https://www.gooogle.com
```